# Collection view is shown on simulator but not on device-very strange

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

This one,is one of the strangest i have seen for a while .

Using iPhone6 on simulator, our app has a *main class*(view controller) that has a `UIScrollview`.

That scrollview loads to its 3 pages,a 3 different `view controllers`(classes).

Each view controller has its own `collection view`.

We load them to the main scroller like that :

```
 self.someviewcontroller=[[someviewcontroller alloc] initWithPosition:0];
  self.someviewcontroller2=[[someviewcontroller2 alloc] initWithPosition:1];
[scroller addSubview:self.someviewcontroller];
[scroller addSubview:self.someviewcontroller1];
```

Now these `someviewcontroller` has a `UICollectionview` inside it.
In simulator we see the collection view and it works great.
On the actual iPhone6, you just dont see the collection view !
(his delegates are still being called- all cells delegates are called)

the `someviewcontroller` looks like that :

```
    - (id)initWithPosition:(NSInteger)position  
    {
        if (self = [super init])
        {
            myPosition = position;
         }
        return self;
    }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 //some stuff here
//collection view
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    self.collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
```

Why i dont see the collection view in the actually device? does it has to do with the fact that it is inside a view controller that is inside a scroller ??

btw:
on the simulator, i see the collection view *only* if its in a view controller that is in page number0 in the scroller. if its in viewcontoller in page 1 , i also not see it on the simulator.